# PYQT4 QlistWidget : currentItem and selectedItem different when currentItemchaged is called ,why ?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, qlistwidget, currentitem

So I curious to know how does the currentItem()) and selectedItems() methods of the QlistWidget actually work.

What I have(simplified):
-I have a QlistWidget with a list of items(usersList)
-I have QAbstractViewItem.extendedSelection activated 
-I have QLineEdit(userAge)
-I have a dictionary DataDict with  key:value ==> ListItem.text():QlineEdit.text())

-I have connected the userAge.textChanged to the function saveData

```
 **def** *saveData*():
     currentItem=str(usersList.currentItem().text())

     DataDict[currentItem]=QlineEdit.text()
```

-I have connected usersList.currentItemChanged to the function loadData:

```
 **def** *loadData*(current,_previous):
      currentItem=current.text()
      #get data
      data=dataDict[currentItem]
      #clear previous data
      userAge.clear()
      #set Data
      userAge.setText(data)
```

what I want to do/problem(simplified):

-right now the saving/loading of the data in the UI works for one item
(currentitem)  but I want the user to be able to select multiple Items
change the usersAge and setData to all the selectedItems , and I'm trying to do this by modifying my saveData() like so:

```
   def  saveData():
     for item in usersList.selectedItems():
         currentItem=str(item.text())
         DataDict[currentItem]=QlineEdit.text()
```

-the problem now is that when I changed currentItem by clicking on another one item the data of the previous gets overwritten by the current loaded one

-I know whats probably happening is (if i'm not wrong):
               1.I click in another item(changing current Item)
               2.currentItemChanged is triggered
               3.loadData() is called
               3.a userAge.clear() is called 
               3.b userAge.textChanged is triggered
               3.c saveData() is called (now with empty)
               3.d userAge.setText(data)
               3.e userAge.textChanged is triggered
               3.f saveData() is called(with the loaded data)

-In my head it should work fine because currentItem/selectedItem are the same, but what is causing the problem is that when saveData() is called  , the currentItem and the selectedItem are different,  if I print currentItem.text() and selectedItems()[0].text()  when I entered savData()

I noticed that currentItem= currentItem (which is correct)  but selectedItems()[0].text() = previousItem (which is wrong cause only the currentItem is selected)

why is this happening? what am I doing wrong? or what am I missing? 
why is the selection not getting updated when you changed current Item?

I a newbie so I might be doing something wrong , but if not could someone please help me understand what is happening?

thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

so after playing around and trying some different stuff (not logical just trying)  I found a solution to this problem , so what I have to do is called the usersList.setCurrentItem(current)  inside the loadData()  function like so:

```
**def** *loadData*(current,_previous):
  currentItem=current.text()
  #get data
  data=dataDict[currentItem]
  #clear previous data
  userAge.clear()
  #FIX
  usersList.setCurrentItem(current)
  #set Data
  userAge.setText(data)
```

this seems very redundant to me , but by doing this, when I print  currentItem and selectedItems()[0] (when only one item selected)  in saveData() it prints currentItem==selectedItems()[0] , so the onlye data getting overwritten is the currentItem,selectedItems()[0] which is own data
which give me the behaviour I want

but I'm still clueless why this happens and why this fixes the issue

cheers